# A way to change default scrollbar position? CSS Grid

Tags: css

Is there a way to load a page with scrollbar thumb in bottom position instead on a default top one? Kind of like chats work with latest messages always being the ones you see first.

I tried to do this by aligning content to the bottom of the grid item (which doesn't seem to work at all for some reason) but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

My code, if it needed:

```
 #interface {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 20% 10%;
    grid-template-rows: 5vh minmax(0, 70vh) 15vh;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#passages {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
    overflow:scroll;
    align-content: end;
}
```

Images:

[Right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4HE8.jpg)

[As I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tKnj.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063627/force-scrollbar-to-bottom might give some insights but it would be better if you could add the HTML code in question as well so we can see how it's structured and related to the CSS

Comment: @iLuvLogix Thanks for the link! As for HTML, unfortunately don't really think, that I will be able to, since it's Twine game engine - I am just tryng to customize it's interface. It's basically just text passed to passages div.

Comment: Not without using javascript

Comment: @Phaelaxz Oh, okay, gonna start looking in that direction then. Thank you!

Comment: do you have some images on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @DavidSalomon Yes, I added links to the question. It fairly simple, I have text in grid item, and when user clicks "next" some more text added to it, but the problem is that when page updates srollbar thumb is in top position, so the user have to scrolldown every time and he might even not know that something have changed, since new text is hidden on the bottom of item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column-reverse` :

```css
#interface {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 20% 10%;
    grid-template-rows: 5vh minmax(0, 70vh) 15vh;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#passages {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
    overflow:scroll;
    align-content: end;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="interface">
<div id="passages">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god.  Thank you, you saved me so much time! I hope you won't find me too insolent if I ask one more question: I tried and it seem to not work with "align-content: center" so that small(first ones) amounts of text would still appear in the center of grid item, am I right or I did something wrong and it's totally possible?

Comment: @AlexBryer sorry your question is unclear to me, are you talking about the word "saves" that appears on your screenshots ? Anyway, I suggest you address this issue in a new question.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks again)